# How to pass commands into the shell opened in new Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-terminal

I can run the following command from PowerShell to start another PowerShell instance, change the window name,  then run `ls` command and open Chrome to a specific web site from the new PowerShell instance.

```
start powershell `
"-noexit", `
"`$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle` = 'list files and goto SO'; `
ls ;`
Start-Process chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com/"
```

How do I do the same thing in the new Windows Terminal (wt)?

Running the following from PowerShell opens wt to the "Windows Powershell" profile and changes the title of the "Windows Powershell" tab.

```
start wt '-p "Windows PowerShell" --title  "list files and goto SO" '
```

However, I cannot pass in any additional commands to get executed in the Windows Terminal "Windows Powershell" profile shell.

Is this currently possible?

I am aware of the following:
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/pull/3495
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows

Comment: Simply put, as you have discovered, you can't, because it's simply not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [*Using command-line arguments for Windows Terminal*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows) article appears to me a bit unclear (or even confusing). However, the (default) `wt` command `new-tab` offers the `commandline` parameter along with (or instead of?) the `-p profile-name` one. So **use a command line** as defined by `powershell.exe -Help`. Something like

- `wt PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {$Host}"` from Windows `cmd` command prompt, or
- `` wt.exe PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {`$Host}" `` from an open `PowerShell` session (note **escaped dollar sign** and **explicit use of the `.exe` file extension** in **`wt.exe`**).

<strike>BTW, *I don't see any difference between `wt PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {$Host}"` and `wt -p "Windows PowerShell" PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {$Host}"`.* In both cases, the `PowerShell` starts in  a `wt` tab…</strike> It's because I have default profile set to *Windows PowerShell* in `settings.json` under `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\`.

Unfortunately, a semicolon (`;`) is used in a `wt` instance to create a new tab; hence, it's not applicable as a PowerShell command separator. Therefore,

- `wt PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {$Host; $PWD}"` will **fail**. <strike>I don't know how-to escape that</strike> however I know **a workaround**:
- `wt PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {$Host, $PWD}"`; although doing that is still possible, I found a ***regular* solution** recently: use the `\` (backslash) as an escape character for the `;` (semicolon) it `wt` parameters:
- `wt PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {$Host\; $PWD}"`.

For more complex/advanced commands, apply the [Grouping operator `( )`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#grouping-operator--) as follows in a use case similar to yours (run from from an open `PowerShell` session):

```
wt.exe PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {(`$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle='list files and goto SO'),`$PWD.Path,(Push-Location D:\Downloads),(ls e*.ps1),(Start-Process -PassThru chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com/)}"
```

with the following result in Windows Terminal:

[image: Windows Terminal]

Above code will suspend parent `Powershell` until the terminal is closed; if you want to continue in  parent `Powershell` then use

```
Start-Process wt.exe -ArgumentList "PowerShell.exe", "-NoExit", "-Command", "& {(`$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle='list files and goto SO'),`$PWD.Path,(Push-Location D:\Downloads),(ls e*.ps1),(Start-Process -PassThru chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com/)}"
```

### Edit:

*Windows Terminal* uses the `\` (backslash) as an escape character for the `;` (semicolon). Hence, the latter workaround I replace with equivalent **regular** solving:

```
Start-Process wt.exe -ArgumentList "PowerShell.exe", "-NoExit", "-Command", "& {`$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle='list files and goto SO'\;`$PWD.Path\;Push-Location D:\Downloads\;ls e*.ps1\;Start-Process -PassThru chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com/}"
```

or, with `-p` flag:

```
Start-Process wt.exe -ArgumentList '-p "Windows PowerShell"', "PowerShell.exe", "-NoExit", "-Command", "& {`$Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle='list files and goto SO'\;`$PWD.Path\;Push-Location D:\Downloads\;ls e*.ps1\;Start-Process -PassThru chrome.exe https://stackoverflow.com/}"
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  Now if only there was a way to get the command to open in a new tab in the same wt instance.

Comment: `wt PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {$Host.UI\; $PWD.Path}"; PowerShell.exe -NoExit -Command "& {$PWD.Path\;$Host.UI}"` or something similar?

Comment: This creates a new Windows Terminal with two tabs that run the respective commands, but it does not launch a new tab within the existing Windows Terminal host. ```start wt "PowerShell.exe", "-NoExit", "& {`$Host.UI\; `$PWD.Path}", ';', "PowerShell.exe", "-NoExit", "& {`$PWD.Path\;`$Host.UI}"```

Comment: @Clay please ask another question about this request (which extends topic of the current one)…

Comment: backslash worked for me.